# regular Discrete Time Markov Chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have a transition matrix $P$. I know that $P$ is regular if all $p^{(n)}_{ij}>0$ for some $n \geq 1$. Is there an algorithm that can help me to verify whether $P$ is regular without calculating $P^n, n=0,1, \ldots, \infty$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the eigenvalues of the transition matrix $P$.
If the eigenvalue $1$ is unique then $P$ is regular,
i.e. if the multiplicity of that eigenvalue is one then
it is regular otherwise it is not regular.

You also have that if the transition matrix $P$ is irreducible and at least one 
entry of the main diagonal is
nonzero, then it is regular. The markov chain is irreducible when all its
states communicate with each other.

---

**edit:**

My answer is not quite right but we decided to not delete it. Together with the comments it might help someone.

Read the comments.

"The crucial point is that $1$ is the only eigenvalue on the unit circle. The multiplicity of the eigenvalue $1$ being $1$ does not guarantee regularity (in any sense)" - Byron Schmuland

Comment: The matrix $P=\pmatrix{0&1\cr 1&0}$ is not regular, but the eigenvalue 1 has multiplicity one.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thanks Byron. I will delete my answer. Ahh...i thought i was right this time :)

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Hi Byron...Are there different defintions 
for what it means for a markov chain 
to be regular? In this paper it says
"The necessary and sufficent conditions
for a simple Markov chain to be regular
, that is, for $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}
p_{ij}^{(n)} = P_j$, are that the latent
root 1 of the stochastic matrix for the 
chain be simple, and the remaining roots
have moduli less than 1"

Comment: [The condition of regularity in simple markov chains](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1956AuJPh...9..387G)

Comment: @J Yes, there are slightly different definitions depending on the author. Your solution focuses on the wrong eigenvalue (in my opinion). The crucial point is that 1 is the only eigenvalue on the unit circle. The multiplicity of the eigenvalue 1 being 1 does not guarantee regularity (in any sense). (P.S. I'm glad that you undeleted your answer!)

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Ok, I keep it undeleted. Together with the comments it might help someone.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Maybe i should quote  you in the answer : "The crucial point is that 1 is the only eigenvalue on the unit circle. The multiplicity of the eigenvalue 1 being 1 does not guarantee regularity (in any sense)" So my answer doesnt confuse anyone. Is that ok? If they dont read the comments i mean.

Comment: @JK That's a good idea.